Why is there a thick blue border appearing over elements when its in focus?
Can someone please help to me understand why html elements are showing a thick blue color instead of a light blue color when active/infocus. This is what I'm talking about:

Before, everything used to have this outline color: 
why did it change and how can I make everything in lightning have the outline color in picture 2?

I think this is a browser issue, not a Salesforce issue. Which browser are you using? Did you notice this in others? For example, in Edge vs Firefox? Or Chrome vs Firefox?

I'm using chrome
